# How to change Layout Right to Left at runtime according to Locale

Tags: java

I am not able to decide the tile of this question so may be Title is mismatching with my question.

I have developed an Java Desktop application but now we have to deliver that desktop application to an client whose language is Right-To-Left (Arabic). So according to Locale is it possible to change layout of application?

Is it possible to do so? Or I have to make another copy of application where layout as per Right-To-Left.

Comment: The answer to this question is that it depends on the layout(s) that you're using. What happened when you wrote a little example program to test things out?

Comment: @KevinWorkman, I tried with Arabic language text. Text is printing correctly means Right-To-Left but layout means label remains at left side which is suppose to at Right side.

Comment: What layout are you using?

Comment: @KevinWorkman ,I am using Frames and panels.

Comment: Right... and what layouts are you using in those frames and panels?